# When I try to edit a DT table, it returns an error with 'dimnames'

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, dt

I'm a beginner in shiny...

I'm trying to make my shiny app to have an editable table with two calculated columns (the first and the last).

The user defines some parameters, including the number of columns of the table.

The app creates a matrix with normal samples using some parameters directly stablished by the user and others calculated in the code (calculations that I don't show here).

It renders this matrix as a table, and it should accept editions in it, but **when I press ctrl+enter after editing somehting, it shows me the error:**

**"Warning: Error in <-: length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent".**

The code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)


dt_output = function(title, id, button_id) {
  fluidRow(
    column(
      12, 
      h1(title),
      hr(), 
      DTOutput(id),
      actionButton(button_id, "Delete data")
    )
  )
}


render_dt = function(data, editable = 'cell', server = TRUE, ...) {
  renderDT(data, selection = 'none', server = server, editable = editable, ...)
}


generate_normal_data <- function(n, mi, sigma, LI, LS) {

result_matrix <- matrix(NA, nrow = 100, ncol = n + 2)
#Code that returns a matrix with normal samples in "n" columns + two calculated columns (the first and the last)

return(result_matrix)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  
  theme = bs_theme(version = 4, bootswatch = "sandstone"),
  
  titlePanel("Simulador B-ATTRIVAR SS S2"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("n", "n"),
      numericInput("mi","mi"),
      numericInput("sigma","sigma"),
      numericInput("S2p","S2p"),
      numericInput("alpha","alpha"),
      numericInput("lambda","lambda"),
      numericInput("beta","beta"),
      actionButton("runButton", "Execute")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Results and Chart",
                 
                 tableOutput("results"),
                 plotOutput("chart")),
        tabPanel("Insert data", 
                 dt_output('Double-click to edit table cells', 'x1', 'deleteButton'),
                 actionButton("plotDataButton", "Plot Data")),
        
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  d1 <- reactiveValues(ults = NULL)
  
  observe({
  d1$ults <- generate_normal_data(input$n, input$mi, input$sigma, req(res$ults[[6]]), req(res$ults[[7]]))
  names(d1$ults[,1]) <- "Yd"
  for (i in 2:(req(input$n)+1)) {
    names(d1$ults[,i]) <- cbind("X",as.character(i))
    
  }
  names(d1$ults[,req(input$n)+2]) <- "S2"
  })
  
 #Edition
  observeEvent(input$x1_cell_edit, {
    
    d1$ults <<- editData(d1$ults, input$x1_cell_edit, 'x1')
})

  res <- reactiveValues(ults = NULL)
  res2 <- reactiveValues(ults = NULL)

  #observeEvent(input$runButton, {

  #code that calculates a vector

  #res$ults <- calculated_vector
#})

  output$x1 = render_dt(
    req(d1$ults),list(target = 'row', disable = list(columns = (req(input$n) + 2)))
    )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: There are a number of problems with your app code that make it impossible to debug:. Please provide a minimally reproducible example: # 1. Need library(shiny)
# 2. Delete extra parentheses at end of ui
# 3. fluidpage -> fluidPage
# 4. Need library DT
# 5. result_matrix not defined
# 6. res$ults not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it... just had to add "rownames = FALSE" into "editData":

```
observeEvent(input$x1_cell_edit, {
    
    d1$ults <<- editData(d1$ults, input$x1_cell_edit, 'x1', rownames = FALSE)
})
```